# SASS Settings in Foundation

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I've installed `SASS` version and  i have the `_settings.scss`  file which is all are
commented.

[image: settings file]

How can i do some settings or some modifications here?
Shall i remove the comments and recompile?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's how you do this. And if you need some in depth changes then instead of importing foundation in app.scss file you can import elements individually(most likely you don't need all of them) so you can modify components separately while all other components will load from foundation gem and update.